# Event with probability 0 of happening for countable and uncountable set

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I know that if we have a uniform distribution over an interval of real number, say $[0,1]$, then the probability of sampling a particular number in $[0,1]$ is $0$. My question is if I take out all the irrational numbers from this interval and try to sample a rational number from the remaining elements, does it make any difference in terms of the probability? My concern is before we are sampling from an uncountable infinite set, now we are sampling from a countable infinite set, so there might be some change.

Comment: You are trying to calculate the conditional probability on an event of probability zero. The conventional wisdom is that this is undefined (akin to division by zero): see also [Borel-Kolmogorov paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_paradox). Note also in your case, obviously you cannot have probability on each rational number and make it translation-invariant: let the probability $P(X=q_i)=p_i=\alpha, 0\le\alpha\le 1$, you would need to have $\sum_ip_i=\sum_i\alpha=1$ which is impossible (the sum converges to $0$ if $\alpha=0$, diverges otherwise.

Comment: As for whether you can have a probability space on $P(\mathbb Q)$ _in principle_, of course yes, but the choice is rather arbitrary. One example: pick an enumeration of $\mathbb Q$ and set $P(X=q_i)=\frac{1}{2^i}, i=1,2,3,\ldots$ where $q_i$ is $i$th rational number in your chosen enumeration.

Comment: @StinkingBishop I think my question is essentially asking is there any difference between taking limit to countable and uncountable infinity for $\frac{1}{n}$. I don't quite follow your reasoning on the translation-invariant part (my background in measure theory is quite weak...).

Comment: And I don't understand what it has to do with the limit of $\frac{1}{n}$. The uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ is given as a particular integral (see: [Probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Formal_definition) ) where the PDF is $\begin{cases}1&0\le x\le 1\\0&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$. On the other hand, any probability distribution on $[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$ can only be given as a sequence of probabilities $p_i=P(X=q_i)$ for each rational number $q_i, i=1,2,3,\ldots$, however you want to enumerate them - and no "uniformity" is possible.

Comment: Also, the answer here may help you: [Countable vs. Uncountable Probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141799/countable-vs-uncountable-probability)